# How to toggle a bootstrap dropdown with a button located somewhere else on the page?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Every example I've seen so far, the dropdown is below the trigger button. What if I want a very long dropdown to popup in the middle of the page?

This code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
   id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
     Dropdown
     <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

I'd like the dropdown and the button-trigger to be at different location.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index5.html) will fit for you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be mandatory to have the **dropdown trigger** inside a **.dropdown** tag as it is said in the bootstrap documentation.

[bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

The only thing you can do if you want to reduce the html code is to define
 your **dropdown trigger** and menus in an external scripts and fill your **.dropdown** tag after that like this :

```
<div class="dropdown">      
</div>

<script>
    var dropdownButtonTrigger = '<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"'
                               +'id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">'
                               +'Dropdown'
                               +'<span class="caret"></span>'
                               +'</button>';
   var dropdownList = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">'
                    + '<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>'
                    + '<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>'
                    + '<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>'
                    + '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>'
                    + '<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>'
                    + '</ul>';      

    $('.dropdown').append(dropdownButtonTrigger);
    $('.dropdown').append(dropdownList);
</script>
```